# Probability of an event in relation to a marker - effect plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, effects

I am stuck on the following problem:
I want to create a plot that shows the probability of an event (stroke) in relation to the concentration of a biomarker. Further, the x-axis should be log-transformed.

Can somebody help me out?

Currently I got so far:

```
library(effects)
glm_mb<- glm(data =  df_analysis, event_stroke ~ nsa(log2(biomarker), c(2000,4000,8000,12000)))
gdf.eff.mb <- Effect("biomarker", glm_mb)
plot(gdf.eff.mb, main= FALSE,rug=T)
```

However, I am not sure if this is correct and I cannot transform the axis. Next, I would like to add a second line/curve for a second event (bleeding).

This is how it should look like:
[Desired Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvPyJ.png)

Thank you, Stephan

Comment: If you use ggplot you can transform the axis with + scale_x_continuous(trans =‘log2’). 
To add a second line, convert your data to long format and use geom_smooth() with aes(group = event_type))

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get efficient support please provide a minimal reproducible example. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>